# Android toString method for a listView

Tags: android, tostring

In my main activity class, I have this code:

```
    DatabaseHandler db;
    List<Contact> contactList;
    ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter;
```

The following goes in the onCreate method:

```
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        contactList = db.getAllContacts();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this,
                R.layout.home_screen_contacts_view, contactList);
        contactsView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now my ListView (which is `contactsView`) is showing the contacts in the way that I am specifying in the `toString()` method in the `Contact` class like so:

```
public String toString() {
        return _id + ". " + firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

Here is my question: I would like the user to be able to set which way he/she wants the contacts in the listview to display. Eg, instead of `id + firstname + lastname` maybe they want `lastName + firstName`. So how can I implement this. Would I need two `toString()` methods? Im not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can add another variable to indicate which format the user wants to use (save it in `SharedPreferences`, perhaps?), then use it in `toString()` like this:

```
public static int FORMAT_TYPE = 0; // format to use

private String displayToUI(){
    switch(FORMAT_TYPE){
        case 0: // default
            return _id + ". " + firstName + " " + lastName;
        case 1: // custom user preference
            return lastName + firstName;
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return displayToUI();
}
```

Comment: Thats a really neat idea having an external method determine what the toString method should return. Ill try it out and get back to you later because I must go to uni.